# Ubuntu 20.04 booting issue in Legion 5i

Tags: dual-boot, acpi

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in my Legion 5i but there was ACPI error(bug) and AE not found. I have done modifications in GRUB by adding "nomodeset" at the end of the line "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=..." Now it finally boots up but the initial errors still persists.

This is what the screen look like:

> [image: This is what the screen look like]
>
> [    0.213475] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCI0.I2C2.TPD0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/dsU)load2-162)
> [    0.213492] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/ps object-220)
> [    0.213530] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCI0.I2C3.TPL1], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/dswload2-162)
> [    0.213535] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/ps object-220)
> [    0.612012] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
> [    0.776366] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
> /dev/sda4: clean, 208217/33406976 files, 4383755/133619712 blocks
> [   29.269500] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains HGDS but no WRDS

Comment: What happens if you disable ACPI in the BIOS?

Comment: Boot and do `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)` to cure your decoding error, and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer or motherboard. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema My exact pc model number is legion 5 15imoh5. I was trying a few things from internet and now it is not even booting too. I ran the commands you mentioned,  sharing the output. Bios version EFCN38WW

Comment: What "things did you try from the Internet" that's now caused your computer not to boot?

Comment: @heynnema I tried installing nvidia-340 as brightness control was not working and it was showing some different gpu in about section although clearly I have a gtx 1650. After the installation a nvidia.conf file was generated at usr/etc/x11/xorrg.conf.d/ I edited that with brightness permission-1 kind, can't exactly remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**BIOS**

Lenovo Legion 5-15IMH05

You have BIOS version EFCN38WW.

There's a newer BIOS available, version EFCN39WW, from 14 Sep 2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-5-17imh05/downloads/DS544633).

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**initramfs**

Boot to Recovery Mode (newest kernel), Root Access, and use this command to take care of the decoding error:

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`

**Nvidia**

First, in `Software & Updates`, Additional Drivers tab, confirm that the nouveau video driver is selected.

Then purge all of the old Nvidia stuff with:

`sudo apt-get purge *nvidia*`

`reboot` # (reboot normally)

The current Nvidia driver for your GTX 1650 is version 450.80, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/) or [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/results/164073/).

Then install the 450.80 version and reboot. Verify `Software & Updates`, Additional Drivers tab.

**Update #1:**

Reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113676/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-ubuntu-20-04-booting-issue-in-legion-5i).